# Take off a tag without scissors

Tags: home, substitute-tool

I need to take off a tag without scissors. I also can't just rip it off because I have a broken wrist (which is also my dominant hand).

I'm ideally looking for something easy and around the house. Are there any tools to help me hack my life?

[image: tag to be removed]

Comment: Do you have a knife at your house? I would think that that would work, unless of course, you can't hold the knife and the tag at the same time.

Comment: @michaelpri I've got a knife, but I'm looking for something that ideally uses one hand. Holding a knife in my left hand, and a splint in a broken hand might not be a good idea...

Comment: I might have interpreted "tag" the wrong way: do you mean a price tag like those attached to clothes or a "sticky" tag like those attached to the front / back side of books? [This](http://students.risd.edu/students/jkim54/collection/img/tag4.jpg) or [this](http://i01.i.aliimg.com/wsphoto/v0/556283079_1/Sell-Label-Sticker-Tag-Tally-Sticky-Note.jpg)?

Comment: Or to extend on comment by @kos,  a laundry tag sewed into the garment?

Comment: Yes, it's a tag on a garment. I'll see if I can upload a picture of it :)

Comment: I'm wondering why you don't possess a single pair of scissors - not even nail scissors?

Comment: @Bamboo My issue is that with a broken wrist, it's incredibly hard to cut something.

Comment: If its your right hand, then yes, scissors would be next to useless...is it a kimble tag, that is, a longish, thin bit of plastic threaded through the garment and then to the tag?

Comment: Let me get a picture of this.

Comment: Thanks for the picture. If your goal is to keep it from flapping around or scratching your forearm, I have a workaround that doesn't involve cutting: you can fold it against the outside of the cast/brace and tape it there.

Comment: Yeah, I've meant to get this picture up a way while back, but here it is. @BrettFromLA That's an amazing idea. Post it as an answer!

Comment: @Zizouz212 If you insist! :)

Comment: This question doesn't make sense. Scissors are the easiest way to cut a tag. If you have a disability that makes it impossible to use scissors, what inconvenient substitute tool can you possibly hope to be able to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tags in that picture are really big! If your goal is to keep them from flapping around or scratching your forearm, I have a workaround that doesn't involve cutting: Fold the tags against the outside of the cast/brace, and tape them there.

[image: arrow displaying how to fold tag]

Answer (score 2):

Nail clippers should do the trick (a little bit at a time). They're easy to operate with just one hand.

[image]

Comment: Nice suggestion, but they aren't exactly... cutting the tag.

Comment: @Zizouz212 I just saw the picture you uploaded. That's a pretty serious tag! Ordinary fingernail clippers may not be strong enough, as you pointed out. How about bigger toenail clippers?

Answer (score -1):

Speaking of this kind of tags:

[image: picture]

Warming up the tag by any mean should work; however using water as well will be way more effective.

For example, if possible, immerse the object to which the tag is attached to into hot water; otherwise, pour some hot water on the tag using a sponge or warm up the tag by any other mean.

Either way, if using the hot water method, wait until the tag itself is impregnated and hot enough to come off with ease by gently lifting up the sides.

Warming up the tag works because the heat will melt the glue under the tag, leading the glue to lose strenght enough for the tag to come off; using water as well for some reason, IME, greatly improves the effectiveness of this method.